# F# count all present links on html website

Tags: html, web, web-scraping, f#, substring

I am currently trying to create a simple F# function that can given a URL to a html site, count all the links present.

I know that it can be done somehow through counting the number of <a substrings, but not sure on how to actually search through the site and so on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have actually got it working now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HtmlParser` from [FSharp.Data](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlParser.html) package.

```
open FSharp.Data

let doc = HtmlDocument.Load "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_(programming_language)"

let linksCount = doc.Descendants ["a"] |> Seq.length
```